# Graphics Cards - What is Multi View?

Tags: graphics-card, sli

I have been looking at graphics cards, and I notice that some of them feature 'Multi View', only I cannot find a definition of what it is?

What is Multi-view and what is it used for? It is a vendor-specific feature (such as SLI)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nvidia defines Multi View as using multiple video card to drive multiple displays.  From [their website:](http://www.nvidia.com/object/quadro_sli_multiview.html)

> **SLI Multi View**: Combines the power of
>   two identical NVIDIA Quadro PCI
>   Express graphics cards to drive
>   multiple displays, with each GPU
>   dedicated to a single display or to a
>   pair of displays.
>
> Benefits
>
> - View professional applications over multiple displays to increase
>     visual real estate.

[This FAQ](http://www.nvidia.com/object/quadro_sli_faq.html#answer11) adds additon information:

> **SLI Multi View**: Combines the power of
>   two NVIDIA Quadro PCI Express graphics
>   cards to span a single
>   hardware-accelerated OpenGL
>   application window across multiple
>   displays, run a single application per
>   GPU with multiple display outputs, or
>   enable other flexible usage of two PCI
>   Express graphics cards.